# Real advantages of .Net delegates over Java's anon classes?

Tags: java, .net, delegates, anonymous-class

I know a lot of the uses of .Net delegates can be emulated in Java by using a combination of interfaces and anonymous classes, but are there any situations where delegates have a real advantage and there is no Java equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- *Much* more concise syntax in C# with lambda expressions and anonymous methods
- Type inference
- General support for delegates in the language (method group conversions etc)
- Multi-cast delegates with language support
- Events (simple syntax for the observer pattern based on delegates)
- Asynchronous execution via the system thread-pool
- Expression trees with language support

Yes, a lot of it *can* be done in Java, but it's just painful.

Imagine writing LINQ queries but without lambda expressions, extension methods etc. It would be hideous. The same goes for a lot of other places where delegates are the natural solution in C# or .NET - the idiomatic Java solution often *doesn't* use anonymous inner classes because they're so darned ugly.

Answer (score 0):

real closures with anonymous methods in c#

with anonymous classes in java, you have to declare every variable, you use from the outer scope, as final